# What do I need to connect this laptop HD to my new laptop?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop

I spilt water over my ASUS X555LA laptop and now it won't start up. In an attempt to recover files from my HD (which is a 1TB HDD 5400 RPM), I've learnt that it's possible to connect my HD to my new laptop. You can see a photo of it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQDza.jpg). Does anyone know what type of connecting device I need to buy so that I can view the files on the HD in my new laptop? Also does anyone know if I can just view the files straight off without any decryption or anything like that? I had a windows system set up on that HD.. Thanks for any help

Comment: It looks like you have a [HTS541010A9E680, PN 0J26213, MLC DA5218, Hitachi 1TB SATA 2.5" Hard Drive](https://www.google.com/search?q=HTS541010A9E680+0J26213). So an external [SATA docking station](https://www.google.com/search?q=SATA+dock) might be worth looking into. Regarding decryption, it would depend entirely on whether the hard drive was encrypted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am in no way affiliated to Amazon...or star tech...but something like this will do the trick.
 https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00HJZJI84/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_i_.iG4AbWZ3S0GH

Remove the drive, connect to this adapter and then plug into into usb of another machine.

Comment: Thank you. Is the key word that my HD has "SATA"? That's what I need to look for?

Comment: 2.5 inch SATA is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You have a standard 2.5" SATA drive - so there are lots of options - 2 main ones -

The easiest way is to get some kind of HDD to USB converter. This can either be a stand-alone convertor, a frame or an enclosure - for a one off, a convertor us all you need, but if you get an enclosure you can then use your drive as a portable drive. A 2.5" enclosure is also simplest because it will only have 1 USB cable - because 2.5 and 3.5 inch drives have the same interface, converters normally have external power (for the 3.5" drive) - so an enclosure is ideal.

While an enclosure will normally work, very occasionally it won't show the data correctly due to geometry differences in the way a drive is recognised externally - in that case you would need to plug the drive into another computer to pull the data off. This is generally not a problem though.